# findHomography() / 3x3 matrix - how to get rotation part out of it?

Tags: opencv, matrix, rotation, translation, vector-graphics

As a result to a call to findHomography() I get back a 3x3 matrix mtx[3][3]. This matrix contains the translation part in mtx[0][2] and mtx[1][2]. But how can I get the rotation part out of this 3x3 matrix?

Unfortunaltely my target system uses completely different calculation so I can't reuse the 3x3 matrix directly and have to extract the rotation out of this, that's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it for my own meanwhile: There is an OpenCV function RQDecomp3x3() that can be used to extract parts of the transformation out of a matrix.

Comment: how exactly are you doing it? This is exactly what I want to do as well!

Comment: @jlarsch: finally I implemented it for my own: put the resulting matrix returned by findHomography() into an own array and then pick the Z-rotational part:    x.x=mtxin->m[0];
    x.y=mtxin->m[4];
    x_length=vector2d_length(&x);

   y.x=mtxin->m[1];
   y.y=mtxin->m[5];
   y_length=vector2d_length(&y);
   if(x_length > y_length)
   {
      ref.x=1.0;
      ref.y=0.0;
      *angleZ =vector2d_angle(&ref,&x);
      if (x.y< 0) *angleZ*=-1.0;
   }
   else
   {
      ref.x=0.0;
      ref.y=1.0;
      *angleZ =vector2d_angle(&ref,&y);
      if (y.x>0) *angleZ*=-1.0;
   }
Result: angleZ

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can't decompose the final transformation matrix into its constituent parts. There are some certain cases where it is possible. For example if the only operation preceding the operation was a translation, then you can do arccos(m[0][0]) to get the theta value of the rotation.

Comment: findHomography() returns a matrix with whatever operations in it (may be there is some scaling included too). In my situation I use it for pattern recognition and I only want to find out the translation and rotation (around Z axis) of the recognised pattern. Possible other values (like rotation around other axes or stretching of the whole thing) result out of inaccuracies/calculation errors only and therefore don't have to be taken into account for the final result. If I would take the whole matrix with these additional information I would add these inaccuracies to my result too...

Comment: I am trying the same as the original post: detecting only translation and rotation. I tried arccos(mtx[0][0]) but mtx[0][0] >1 so I cannot take arccos. Can you be more specific about how to extract the rotation from the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

RQDecomp3x3 has a problem to return rotation in other axes except Z so in this way you just find spin in z axes correctly,if you find projection matrix and pass it to "decomposeProjectionMatrix" you will find better resaults,projection matrix is different to homography matrix you should attention to this point.

Comment: decomposeProjectionMatrix calls RQDecomp3x3 as well, but only after calculating some stuff.