# How to use opencv's decomposeProjectionMatrix to remove scale after findHomography

Tags: opencv

Similar to this question [findHomography() / 3x3 matrix - how to get rotation part out of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369069/findhomography-3x3-matrix-how-to-get-rotation-part-out-of-it) the resulting homography is too aggressive. I'm trying to use it for video stabilization after calcOpticalFlowPyrLK and the image scales forward and backward. I would be ok with rotation around x/y and translation on x/y.

From researching only I discovered I can decompose the homography using decomposeProjectionMatrix but I don't understand how to compose it back for warpPerspective.

Comment: decomposeProjectionMatrix takes a 3x4 projection matrix not a 3x3 homography.  Getting a rotation matrix from a homography is more complicated than you might expect.

Comment: since I'm using this for video stabilization another solution would be to eliminate the outliers, the points of the objects moving in the animation vs the regular goodfeaturestotrack which are relatively stable. not sure how to do that though.