# Reference frame of homography matrix (and how to obtain the motion wrt the first image)?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, homography

The OpenCV function `findHomography` "finds a perspective transformation between two planes". According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693683/output-of-cv2-findhomography-in-opencv-python), if `H` is the transformation matrix, we have (where `X1` is the prior image):

```
X1 = H · X2
```

I am struggling to fully comprehend the reference axes of the parameters in the transformation (translation distances, scaling factors and rotation angle -in a simplified affine transformation case without shear-).

What I am trying to obtain is the camera motion from one image to another, relative to the first image. That is, motion between images expressed as the **translation in the first image's axes**. I assume these translations are the (tx,ty) from the homography matrix, but **corrected using the rotation angle and scaling** parameters. Could someone enlighten me on how to obtain these translation values?

Comment: Does [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781165/2065121) help?

Comment: That answer deals with obtaining the camera pose matrix from the homography matrix and vice versa, but doesn't help me much with this issue.